# Detect which url button was clicked facebook messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm developing an chatbot to facebook, but right now, i'm facing a problem.
The issue is, i want to give to the users the option to select a link and after the user opens it, i want him to give me a feedback about if this was helpfull.

Something like,

> **me:** I've searched and i've found this.
>       http://facebook.com/1  |  http://facebook.com/2
>
> ---
>
> **User:** Clicks on the first link. And i'm notified about that.
>
> ---
>
> **me:** Have you found what you were searching for?
>       Yes  |  No

So, after this i know that the user have clicked on the first link, and the feedback was positive.
Or at least this is what i want to know..
That may sound confusing.

Comment: Are you sending those links just as plain text, or as URL buttons? Either way, I don’t think that is directly possible. But you could of course “proxy” those links via your own script, and pass additional data to help identify the user or the conversation - and then redirect the user to the actual target URL from there.

Comment: Ty for your answer. That solution would probably work more or less. But it will be hard to implement if the user has clicked on the first link, then do not answer if that was the right link and he opens the second link. It seems to me that there are some holes in there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do this. You could append url params to the link and then parse them when the request is received by your webserver.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. There was a time that i was doing like you said, but i'm trying right now the new chat widget of facebook and seems like that new widget won't open if you use the internal browser of facebook.

Comment: That is correct. The webview isn't currently supported for the customer chat plugin.